# Why (unsigned short) 0x8000 0001 is 1 not 65535?

Tags: c, casting

C 11 6.3.1.3, for cast:

> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.

When I try

```
printf("%d", (unsigned short) 0x80000001);
```

I expect the result is `65535` but I got `1`.
Why `1` is returned in this case?

Comment: The max value of `unsigned short` is `0xFFFF`. You're gonna lose some bits during this conversion.

Comment: One more than the maximum unsigned short of 65535 would be... 65536, aka. 0x10000. Take 0x80000001 and continually add 0x10000  until "the value is in the range of the new type". That will happen at unsigned overflow, at which time all that is left is 0x00000001. Tha value is in range of 0x0 .. 0xFFFF, so that's what you get: 1.

Comment: "I expect the result is 65535" That's a rather odd expectation, can you explain it?

Comment: Because I think the cast operator will try to preserve the value as much as possible.

Comment: But now I think @WhozCraig is right, I also misunderstood the Section 6.3.1.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`USHRT_MAX`, in OP's case is 65535.  `(unsigned short) 0x80000001` converts to 1 per C 11 6.3.1.3 as cited.

The `unsigned short 1` is certainly converted to `int 1` per the *integer promotion* as part being an argument to a ... function.  This matches `"%d"` and `"1"` is printed.

Answer (score 4):

- `0x80000001` = `2147483649`
- The maximum value of `unsigned short` is `65535`. One more than that is `65536`.
- "the value is converted by repeatedly... subtracting one more than the maximum value".
- Repeadedly subtracting until value in range (smaller than 65536) is the same as modulus.
- `2147483649 % 65536` = `1`.

But this is the formal theory - in practice, this is the very same as simply taking the lowest 16 bits of `0x80000001`, which is the value `0x0001`.